# How do I access to my variable in an array of array of array?

Tags: php, arrays, file, symfony, variables

I want to access to 'image'

[image]

I reached my array 'questions' with this `$file = $request->files->get('quiz')['questions'];`
but I can't go further

Can you help me please

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Please share the code involved, and specify how this is related to [tag:file] or [tag:symfony]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your screen shot you could,

```
$image = $request->files->get('quiz')['questions'][0]['image'];
```

Each nested level is an array so you can walk all the way down using the array keys.

Note that `[0]` will be the first question, but you probably want all the questions. If so, you can loop over them.

```
foreach ($request->files->get('quiz')['questions'] as $question) {
    $image = $question['image'];
    //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The scalaire value on the get is depreciated now.

You can use the "all" :

```
foreach ($request->files->all('quiz')['questions'] as $question) {
    $image = $question['image'];
}
```